# Merge many lists into one using a pattern

Tags: r, lapply, do.call

I have many data files that I want to merge. They are names with a certain pattern.
I managed to import them into the Global Environment, so there are now many lists waiting to be merged into one.
Is there a way to do this using a pattern?
Here is what I did until now:

```
    files <- list.files(pattern = "summary_.*RData") # any file in the directory that starts with 'summary_'
    for (i in files) {
      load(i)
    }

    names_of_lists <- list.files(pattern = "*_bigmarkets") # any object in Global Environment that contains (*)
```

So I get a character vector with the names of all the lists I try to merge, and here I am stuck.

Comment: `mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "_pattern_to_find"), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what output you want but you could try something like

```r
mylists <- list()
for(name in names_of_lists){
mylists <- append(mylists, get(name))
}

rbindlist(mylists)
```

Comment: Thank you. It returns an error but @mael's answer worked